# Is every tensor an element of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

As, the tensor product of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a field $K$ is another vector space over $K$, is it true to say that every tensor is an element of a vector space ? (if we do not consider tensor product of other algebraic structures like modules). Inversely is it true to say that every element of a vector space is a tensor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think tensors are *by definition* elements of the tensor product of vector spaces.
Any vector space $V$ over $K$ is naturally isomorphic to $V\otimes K$, so yes, you can say that any vector in a vector space is tautologically a tensor.

Answer (score 1):

*Everything* is an element of a vector space, tensor or not. Let $x$ be anything, and let $F$ be any field. The simplest example of an $F$-vector space containing $x$ is the vector space in which $x$ is the *only* element. That is:

- The set vectors is $\{ x \}$
- Addition is defined by $x + x = x$
- Scalar multiplication is defined by $r \cdot x = x$

A more interesting fact is that the tensor product of vector spaces are again vector spaces, and have a number of nice multilinear features. (e.g. the binary tensor product is bilinear)

Depending on your precise definitions, every vector is the $1$-long tensor product of itself. i.e.

$$v = \bigotimes_{i=1}^1 v$$

and so any vector in a vector space $V$ is also literally an element of the tensor algebra over $V$.

Comment: Sorry for the necropost, but, how do we evaluate $v\otimes w$, for vectors? For  k,n-tensors; k,n>0 S,T, we have $ S\otimes T:=S(x_1,x_2,..,x_k)T(x_{k+1},....,x_{k+n})$ . I assume we dualize vectors to define this product?

Comment: @Gary: You should ask your question via "ask question" from the main page, not as a comment in a loosely related thread.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a simple-enough that it would not be worth asking it as a stand-alone question.

Comment: Sorry, I just posted it.